# How can I be sure that hbase is running in pseudo-distributed mode?

Tags: hbase, mode

How can I check if my hbase is running in pseudo-distributed mode without looking at the configuration files (`hbase-env.sh` and `hbase-site.xml`).Is there some command through which I can check it other than `jps`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **status** command from HBase shell. Alternatively, you can also use the HBase webui.

Comment: where in the ui does it tell that it is in pseudodistributed.standalone or distributed mode? i do not see any description about it there

Comment: It doesn't tell you directly. But you can see the list of servers over there. If it is pseudo mode there should be only one server in the list and it should be localhost. And if it is the hostname you can match it with hostname of your machine where HMaster is running in order to cross check.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between distributed and pseudo distributed you should check the dfs.replication if it is 1 (and fs.default.name is localhost not the namenode)